# CSS nth-of-type(odd) selector doesn't work anymore after using filterbuttons

Tags: css, filter

How can I keep the CSS odd / even items after selecting a filter (one/two/three)?

In CSS I say `.grid .show:nth-of-type(odd){filter:sepia(100%);}`
But when I select a filter the order is not correct.
It must be something simple.

You can see here on my demo. It needs to be odd/even when I select a button which it doesn't.
https://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/otda1bec/3/

Comment: That's because `:nth-of-type` refers to the type of element, not the type of "_indexed_" class. You actually have to remove the elements from the DOM in order for CSS to correctly guess which is the are odd and which are even.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried page-reloading to the js but then the filter doesn't work obviously. If you have any ideas how to implement this I'm all ears.

Comment: I added an answer of how I would do it, I hope it helps. Also note that `AddClass` and `RemoveClass` were just rather complicated pieces of code that have been solved with the likes of `classList`. Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:nth-of-type` selects the *nth* child of  certain type, but it does not care about classes. If you want this to work consistently, you might want to add and remove items from the list to keep CSS correct, I would suggest the following (note that I have tried to remove any distracting elements here, there's no need for all the classNames and styles so I simplified it to keep the focus:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector( '.grid' );
const filterables = Array.from( wrapper.children );

function filter(c) {

  filterables.forEach(item => {

    if( c === 'all' || item.classList.contains( c ) ){

      wrapper.appendChild( item );

    } else {

      item.remove();

    }

  });

}
```

```css
.grid {
  margin:0 0 50px;
  transition: height .2s;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.grid > * {
  display: block; 
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 20%;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/601/601);
  background-color: var(--color2);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.grid > *:hover {
  filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.grid > * h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%; 
  background: white;
}

.grid > *:nth-child(odd) {
   filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="filter-box">
  <button class="btn all" onclick="filter('all')">all</button>
  <button class="btn one" onclick="filter('one')">one</button>
  <button class="btn two" onclick="filter('two')">two</button>
  <button class="btn three" onclick="filter('three')">three</button>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid">

  <div class="one"><h3>one</h3></div>
  <div class="three"><h3>three</h3></div>
  <div class="three"><h3>three</h3></div>
  <div class="one"><h3>one</h3></div>
  <div class="two"><h3>two</h3></div>
  <div class="one"><h3>one</h3></div>
  <div class="one"><h3>one</h3></div>
  <div class="two"><h3>two</h3></div>
  <div class="three"><h3>three</h3></div>
  <div class="two" ><h3>two</h3></div>
  <div class="two"><h3>two</h3></div>
  <div class="one"><h3>one</h3></div>

</div>
```

You might also have noticed I highly simplified your `filter` function (you made it a little unnecessarily complicated). This filter just checks if a className is present on the element (with `classList.contains()`, see below) and then adds or removes the element from the page flow.

On that note, I would also like to add that in the future, don't write your own `AddClass` and `RemoveClass` methods. Instead use `classList` to do this consistently for you with any edge cases already solved:

```
htmlElement.classList.add( 'show' )
htmlElement.classList.remove( 'show' )
htmlElement.classList.toggle( 'show', optionalBooleanCheckToToggleAppropriately )
```

These methods are much more robust.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nth-child directly instead of nth-of-type

.grid .show:nth-child(odd) {filter:sepia(100%);}

Comment: That wouldn't solve the issue either, as `nth-child` is the same as `nth-of-type` if all your children have the same `tagName`.